# Converting jQuery to Vue - Uncaught TypeError: n.getClientRects is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

How can I write this jquery code in Vue's way?

```
  // Scale the cell item.
  $(document).on('click','.cell-item a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var $this = $(this)
    console.log($this) // [a] - correct
    var parent = $this.closest('.cell')
    var context = $this.closest('.row')

    parent.addClass('large-6 active').removeClass('large-3')
    parent.siblings('.cell').addClass('large-2').removeClass('large-3 large-6 active')
    context.siblings('.row-scale').find('.cell').addClass('large-3').removeClass('large-2 large-6 active')

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 225 // Create white space & ensure item is always centered in viewport
    }, '', function() {
      //
    })
  })
```

Vue template:

```
<div class="large-3 cell cell-item text-center">
    <a href="#" v-on:click="foo">
       <img :src="item.image_src" :alt="item.image_alt">
    </a>
</div>
```

Vue code:

```
   methods: {
    foo(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      var $this = $(event.target)
      console.log($this) // [img] - odd
      var parent = $this.closest('.cell')
      var context = $this.closest('.row')

      parent.addClass('large-6 active').removeClass('large-3')
      parent.siblings('.cell').addClass('large-2').removeClass('large-3 large-6 active')
      context.siblings('.row-scale').find('.cell').addClass('large-3').removeClass('large-2 large-6 active')

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 225 // Create white space & ensure item is always centered in viewport
      }, '', function() {
        //
      })
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.getClientRects is not a function
    at xe.fn.init.offset (bundle.min.js:49544)
    at At.foo (bundle.min.js:139)
    at i (bundle.min.js:58507)
    at t (bundle.min.js:60317)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.e._withTask.e._withTask
```

Also I notice that in the console.log for `console.log($this)` is different in Vue and jQuery.

I get `[a]` in jquery which is **correct**.

But I get `[img]` in Vue which is odd. It should be `[a]`, shouldn't it?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Vue, *use Vue*.  Think of the DOM as a side effect of the app state, don't go rummaging around adding and removing classes on your own.

Instead of DOM traversals, [use Vue's $refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to identify specific elements (when necessary. It often isn't.)

```
// in the template:
<a ref="foo">...</a>
// in the component methods:
this.$refs.foo // <-- the anchor tag.   "this" is the component itself.
```

Instead of adding or removing classes manually, set state variables. The template can check those variables when deciding [which classes to include](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html); no DOM traversal necessary.

```
<div :class="{'large-3': isFoo, 'large-6': !isFoo}">...</div>
    or
<div v-if="isFoo" class="large-3">...</div>
<div v-if="!isFoo" class="large-6">...</div>

data: {
   isFoo: true 
},
methods: {
  foo() {  this.isFoo = !this.isFoo  } // toggle this boolean to swap the classnames
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `event.target`.

> [event.currentTarget] Identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the event occurred.